# How to find method invocations

Tags: java, eclipse, grails, spring-tool-suite

I have a method called `editCustomer` and I want to know when `editCustomer` will be called. How to find references to this function in a project?

Generalizing, how do I build a call hierarchy for any given method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you are using Eclipse or MyEclipse IDE then **Select Method Name** then press **Ctrl+Alt+H** . it will show call hirarchy of the method.

Comment: if there is any search option i.e eclipse Ctrl+H search tool. then You can also search for specific methods. For e.g. If you want to search for isEmpty() method of the string class you have to got to - Search -> Java -> type java.lang.String.isEmpty() and in the 'Search For' option use Method.

You can then select the scope that you require.

Comment: you can see usage of a method or class by selecting the name and then pressing F3.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know. I'm doing exactly the same (selecting the method name), but pressing **Ctrl + Shift + G** = search references in workspace...

Comment: STS is Eclipse plus some extra bits and pieces, so the same shortcuts and features are available in STS, too.